# Why does C# Powershell method work in Windows app but not Web app

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm adding a page to our C# (.NET 4.5) site that will deal with Office 365 account provisioning. I found a helpful [utility](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office365/Office-365-Manage-users-by-cfc96d5e) from Microsoft that is a Windows application that manages Office 365 users via PowerShell calls. This application runs just fine on my Windows 7 machine and allows me to provision/edit user accounts. When I take the exact same `ExcutePowershellCommands()` method from [the tool](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office365/Office-365-Manage-users-by-cfc96d5e/sourcecode?fileId=76569&pathId=1406869875) and put it into my web app it does not work, saying that any of the Office 365 cmdlets I try are not recognized. According to the tool's instructions this is because the user account doesn't have permission to run Windows PowerShell and that makes sense since IIS will run the code under a separate user account from running the native Windows app.

If I surround the `ExcutePowershellCommands()` in my code with a `using()` block that impersonates a local administrator, the function works in my web app. However, if I create a unit test that calls this `ExcutePowershellCommands()` function and run the test I only receive errors that the Office 365 cmdlets are not recognized (even though I still have the function wrapped in a `using()` block impersonating an administrator). Is there a way to find out which account the unit tests are being run under (using TestDriven.Net)? Why does it even matter what account the unit test runs under if I do impersonation?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like the cmdlets for Office 365 are not being loaded for the profile your IIS account is running under. I can't say for sure what you might need to add to get them recognized though. I would start by looking at what is returned by running `gc $profile` to see if they are referenced there.

Comment: Looks like I don't have a profile as there is no file at the path listed when I enter `$profile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue had to do with the `Load User Profile` option in the IIS App Pool for my app being set to `False` on the server (`False` is the default for Windows Server 2008). After reading up on this property I am not entirely sure why this matters for my scenario, but that was the one setting different in IIS on my local machine from what the Web Server had. Now all the PowerShell calls work flawlessly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that when you do create a profile, it can be user or machine specific. Also, it can be scoped for all shells or just powershell. 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx